# Solving a heat equation on a finite interval with Neuman boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions, heat-equation

I am new to Mathematica and need to verify my numerical result.
Can anyone please show me how to solve the following heat equation problem $$ u_t = u_{xx}$$
on the interval $ x \in [0,1]$. The initial condition is
$$ u(x,0) = (\sin(\pi x))^{100} $$ and Neumann boundary conditions
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=0$$

I was hoping to plot the solution at time $t=1$ with respect to $x$. Can anyone please help me? I am a complete novice and the internet was not much help.

Edit: this is what I have managed to use for the equation

```
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] - D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == 
     NeumannValue[0, x == 0] + NeumannValue[0, x == 1], 
    u[0, x] == (Sin[Pi*x])^100}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
```

but I have no idea how to plot

Comment: Could you include what you did with `NDSolve[]`?

Comment: @J.M. thank you, to be honest, I do not know how to use that function

Comment: @J.M. I am very new to Mathematica and only know the basic syntax. I come from Matlab

Comment: There is an entire [Heat Transfer tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.html). That should have everything you need for setting up a numerical solution.

Comment: @user21 thank you. I tried it but I cannot seem to figure it out. May I please ask you to explain to me how to do it?

Comment: Can you show me what you tried than I can explain it.

Comment: @user21 thank you please see the edited answer. Can you please tell me if this is correct for the solution and what I can do about the plot?

Comment: @kroner the backticks really do not look good in $\LaTeX$; I suggest not putting them in in future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"startup aid"

```
U = NDSolveValue[{Derivative[0, 1][u][x, t] ==Derivative[2, 0][u][x, t],
 u[x, 0] == Sin[Pi x]^100 }, 
u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1} , 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> "FiniteElement"  }]
```

`NDSolveValue` evaluates the solution `U[x,t]` as an interpolation object. "FiniteElement" sets the Neumann boundary conditions to zero.

```
Plot3D[U[x, t], {x, 0, 1 }, {t, 0, .1},PlotRange -> {0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for this. I think I understand how to use the solve command now. But how do I plot the solution at T=1 (for a specific value of T) with respect to X as a curve rather than a surface?

Comment: `Plot[U[x,1],{x,0,1}]`

Comment: @user21 "Method" is needed because I omit `Neumann-bc` I think. Without "Method" Mathematica 12 gives a warning but evaluates correct solution .

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, yes, you are correct about that.

Answer (score 4):

Also you can it try this way with version 12.2

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x], t] + DiffusionPDETerm[{u[t, x], {x}}] == 0, 
   u[0, x] == (Sin[Pi*x])^100}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}]

Plot3D[sol[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

To complete this, the following addition:

```
heatSol = 
 NDSolveValue[{HeatTransferPDEComponent[{u[t, x], t, {x}}, <|"ThermalConductivity" -> {{1}}|>] == 0, 
   u[0, x] == (Sin[Pi*x])^100}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

The heattransfer at t =1:

```
Plot[heatSol[1, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]